# Slide sibling element into position where preceding sibling has been removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to mimic the instagram suggestion component on IOS. When one of the element is removed from the parent container, the next sibling next to it slides into position. I have the following implementation but sliding left (animate/transition: marginLeft is what I am having trouble with) Below is some of the code and a link to the pen.

```
    closeIcon.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     var fadeInterval,
         slideInterval,
         closeIconParent = event.currentTarget.parentNode,
         cardParent = closeIconParent.parentNode,
         nextElement = closeIconParent.nextSibling.nextElementSibling;

    fadeInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if(!closeIconParent.style.opacity && !nextElement.style.marginLeft) {
         closeIconParent.style.opacity = 1;
       }
      if(closeIconParent.style.opacity < 0) {
        clearInterval(fadeInterval);
      }else {
        closeIconParent.style.opacity -= 0.1;
      }
    }, 100);
     setTimeout(function() {
       cardParent.removeChild(closeIconParent);
       nextElement.classList.add('instagramCard-moveLeft')
     }, 800)
   })
 })
}
```

[Instagram Like Suggestion](https://codepen.io/ChiefDesignz/pen/wrYWLz)

Comment: I didn't see where you were setting the margin-left attribute in the moveLeft class. It only has transitions being set. I did something similar with a scroll left recently. You may try moving the entire row left and then removing the element that was clicked once it's hidden from view.